# Want to display a value of a loop outside of the loop as a heading in Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewdata

I want to display `@s.CARDNAME` that is used in the for each loop inside the else statement outside the loop as a heading:

```
    <div><h4 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px;">WELCOME <span id="UserName">@ViewData["0"]</span> </h4> </div>
```

**Razor Page Code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div><h4 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px;">WELCOME <span id="UserName">@ViewData["0"]</span> </h4> </div>
    
    
    @if ((Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["hascard"])) == 2)
    {
        <h1>@ViewData["message"]</h1>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="Debit-Card-Boxes">
            @foreach (var s in ViewData["card"] as IEnumerable<DebitCardListingResponeDTOCardInfo>)
            {

                
                <div class="Debit-Card">

                    <div class="credit-card">
                        <img class="Abl-Logo" src="~/images/ABL-Logo.webp" />
                        <div class="chip"><img src="~/images/chip-logo-black-and-white.png" alt="chip"></div>


                        <div class="numbers">@s.ACCOUNTNUMBER</div>
                        <div class="name-and-expiry">
                            <span>@s.CARDNAME</span>
                            <span>@s.CARDEXPIRYDATE</span>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    <a class="activatebtn" href="#modal">Activate</a>

                    <div class="modal" id="modal" tabindex="1">
                        <a href="#" class="modal__overlay" aria-label="Close modal"></a>
                        <div class="modal__content">
                            <a href="#" class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal">&times;</a>



                            <h1 id="genotpheading">OTP Generation</h1>



                            <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Pin:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" id="txtPin" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Confirm Pin:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPin" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>

                        
                    </div>

                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: `I want to display @s.CARDNAME that is used in the for each loop inside the else statement outside the loop as a heading`You want to set all the `CARDNAME`   in a heading?

Comment: Al the s.CardName are the same so I want to display only 1

Answer (score 0):

*I suppose* `@s.CARDNAME` is the same for all records, right? if that is not the case you will have to decide which `cardname` to use since there are many. Anyway if they are the same and you can't change your DTO to separate this property from an IEnumerable.

You can simply cast your viewdata item to IEnumrable and show the first(or last) item's cardname like

```
<h1>Your Card: @(((IEnumerable<DebitCardListingResponeDTOCardInfo>)ViewData["card"]).First().CARDNAME)</h1>
```

also, review [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EgKa8z) for a working example

P.S: You can also `.Last()` simply use any function of LINQ including `ElementAt` as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
<div><h4 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px;">WELCOME <span id="UserName">@(((List<Index3Model>) ViewData["card"])[0].CARDNAME)</span> </h4> </div>
```